# Is manual payment possible for Craft Commerce subscriptions?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I need to allow manual payments for Craft Commerce subscriptions. Typical users for this industry sector require an invoice and then make a bank transfer, and don't want to use credit card. It's low volume, high value so a small amount of admin per sale is OK.

Unfortunately, manual payment gateway option is not available when selecting a gateway for a subscription plan in Craft CP.

So far I've tried:

- Create a free plan, then manually switch user to another plan in CP
  once the user has made a bank transfer. Problem: even a free plan requires a
  credit card with Stripe gateway. Maybe there's a setting I can change
  so if the price is 0 it doesn't need a credit card? Or another
  gateway that will let me do this?
- Create a plan with a free trial, then switch them. Again, can't do
  this without credit card details.
- Create a subscription in Stripe manually. Problem: doesn't sync with Craft. Maybe I can trigger this somehow?
- Create a subscription inside the CP. Problem: doesn't appear to be
  possible. Maybe I can do this by building a custom plugin?

The only workaround I've found that works is to use a dummy gateway, and use hidden fields populated with the dummy credit card details. Is there a security reason I shouldn't do this on a live site? I'm running out of options here.

This is all in test mode on a dev server. Craft & Craft Commerce v4, recent install

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are there features of Commerce subscriptions that you would need? If you are doing manual payments via invoice, why not use a normal Commerce product and the [deferred payment at checkout](https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/4.x/making-payments.html#deferred-payment-at-checkout)?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I did consider that but users log in to the front end and I check their subscription plan/status in order to show them content. 

Also I do need subscriptions functionality in the back end and the client would find this confusing.

If only I could manually create a subscription in the back end like you can in stripe. Seems like a big piece of missing functionality that would be needed even in more standard use cases.

I signed up to CraftQuest by the way ;)